# Delay ember view render till $getJSON isLoaded

Tags: ember.js

The problem with this code is that the render code is entered twice, and the buffer is not where I expect it. Even when I get the buffer, the stuff I push in is not rendered to the screen.

```
App.FilterView = Ember.View.extend({
init: function() {
    var filter = this.get('filter');
    this.set('content', App.ViewFilter.find(filter));
    this._super();
},

render: function(buffer) {
    var content = this.get('content');
    if(!this.get('content.isLoaded')) { return; }

    var keys = Object.keys(content.data);
    keys.forEach(function(item) {
        this.renderItem(buffer,content.data[item], item); 
    }, this);

}.observes('content.isLoaded'),

renderItem: function(buffer, item, key) {
    buffer.push('<label for="' + key + '"> ' + item + '</label>');

}
});
```

And the App.ViewFilter.find()

```
App.ViewFilter = Ember.Object.extend();
App.ViewFilter.reopenClass({
find: function(o) {
    var result = Ember.Object.create({
        isLoaded: false,
        data: ''
    });
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/filter/" + o, function(response) {
        result.set('data', response);
        result.set('isLoaded', true);
    });

    return result;
}
});
```

I am getting the data I expect and once isLoaded triggers, everything runs, I am just not getting the HTML in my browser.

Comment: Are you using the model hook or any other portion of the router?  Generally returning a promise from the model hook is the way this is properly handled.

Comment: No, this is not a route. This is getting some configuration data for generating a customizable form. There are several of these, but they all follow the same pattern for different advanced searches. The advanced search is shown/hidden as part of the object list view as another view. The list view and filter view are going into a container view. So the filter view is just a view and gets config data on the fly.

Comment: Instead of an `Ember.Object` , try using a `new Ember.RSVP.Promise`.  There is good info in the ember API documentation. Located here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.Promise.html#method_reject

The advanced usage looks more along the lines of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: $.getJSON already supports promises .then()  I am working out using this as an example [this](https://github.com/turboMaCk/ember-data-map-demo/tree/master/app). If it works I will post I will update here. @bmeyers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the answer was close to what I had with using jquery then() on the $getJSON call. If you are new to promises, the documentation is not entirely straight forward. Here is what you need to know. You have to create an object outside the promise - that you will return immediately at the end and inside the promise you will have a function that updates that object once the data is returned. Like this:

```
App.Filter = Ember.Object.extend();
App.Filter.reopenClass({
find: function(o) {
    var result = Ember.Object.create({
        isLoaded: false,
        data: Ember.Object.create()
    });
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/filter/" + o).then(function(response) {
            var controls = Em.A();
            var keys = Ember.keys(response);
            keys.forEach(function(key) {
                controls.pushObject(App.FilterControl.create({
                    id: key,
                    label: response[key].label,
                    op: response[key].op,
                    content: response[key].content
                    })
                );
            });

            result.set('data', controls);
            result.set('isLoaded', true);
    });
    return result;
}
});
```

Whatever the function inside then(), is the callback routine that will be called once the data is returned. It needs to reference the object you created outside the $getJSON call and returned immediately. Then this works inside the view:

```
didInsertElement: function() {

if (this.get('content.isLoaded')) {
    var model = this.get('content.data');
    this.createFormView(model);
}
}.observes('content.isLoaded'),

createFormView: function(data) {
    var self = this;

var filterController = App.FilterController.create({ model: data});
    var filterView = Ember.View.create({
    elementId: 'row-filter',
    controller: filterController,
    templateName: 'filter-form'
    });

    self.pushObject(filterView);
},
```

You can see a full app (and bit more complete/complicated) example [here](https://github.com/eviltrout/emberreddit/blob/master/js/app.js)